# OCS 2007: Issues with /LiveServer/MCUFactory

Tags: windows-server-2003, ms-office-communicator

I'm not really an Office Communications Server expert, but just trying to resolve some seemingly minor issues with a new install...

The following error is occurring in the OCS event log, and when I try to visit https://servername:444/LiveServer/MCUFactory in Internet Explorer to test the address, I just get a "page cannot be displayed" error. I can telnet to port 444 on the server and verify that the port is open and listening. Any ideas?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   OCS MCU Infrastructure
Event Category: (1022)
Event ID:   61013
Date:       7/28/2009
Time:       8:47:42 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   COMM2
Description:
The process DataMCUSvc(1284) failed to send health notifications to the MCU factory at https://servername:444/LiveServer/MCUFactory/. 
Failure occurrences: 29, since 7/28/2009 8:40:27 AM.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [**MS Forums post**](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicationsservermcu/thread/2b1ca53a-ce9f-4081-8e29-3f97c85f4d7d) where someone claims to have resolved this by removing extraneous root CA certs.  I'd be a little wary on that one, but hey...

[**Here's another one**](http://social.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/commmunicatorim/thread/512bccc3-d624-4b11-91c1-5d52aca3c195/) that says to check things like cert trusts and that the cert is enabled for all purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar when one front end could not talk to the other front end in a load balancer environment. Either the LB name/address, or the actual FE name/address of the other box, was used ... can't remember ... I think both must be operational.